# Using React how do I toggle the visibility of a nested component from a container component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

## Goal

I am trying to mimic a List Control Component in **React** and **Redux** based on the [Google Material Design layout](https://material.google.com/components/lists-controls.html#lists-controls-types-of-list-controls).

The list control will allow you to **create**, **rename** and **delete** items in the list without navigating to a new page.

The actions for **renaming** and **deleting** a list item will be shown in a **popup menu component** triggered by clicking a link on each list item.

## Current Component Structure

I have a top level Container component **ListItemPage** linked to Redux i am using to maintain the state of the list before i push the changes into the store.

In **ListItemPage** i am rendering a list of items and each item has a unique **Menu Component**

### ListItemPage Component

```
class ListItemPage extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    onMenuClick(){}
    onRename(){}
    onDelete(){}

    render () {
        const { listItems } = this.props;

        return(
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {
                        listItems.map(listItem =>
                            <li>
                                <a href={`/items/${listItem.id}`}>
                                    {listItem.title}
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" onClick={onMenuClick}>
                                    <i className="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                                </a>
                                <Menu
                                    showMenu={showMenu}
                                    onRename={onRename}
                                    onDelete={onDelete}/>
                            </li>
                        )
                    }
                <ul>
                <a href="#" onClick={null}>
                    <i className="material-icons">add</i>
                </a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
    return {
        listItems: state.listItems
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(listItemActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ListItemPage);
```

### Menu Component

```
const Menu = (showMenu, onDelete, onRename) => {
    if(showMenu) {
        return(
            <nav>
                <a href="#" onDelete={onDelete}>Delete</a>
                <a href="#" onRename={onRename}>Rename</a>
            </nav>
        );
    }

    return null;
}

export default Menu;
```

### Redux Store Data Structure

```
let listItems = [
    { id: 1, title: 'Item A' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Item B' },
    { id: 3, title: 'Item C' }
];
```

## Problem

I am unable to figure out how i show and hide the unique menu componenent based on the list item **onClickEvent**.

I was thinking of some how passing in a bool for that unqiue item of **showMenu** but i am unsure where to define this for each item, or even if this is the best way to do this.

I know i can use **Refs** to achieve this but i would prefer not to given that it is advised to only use Refs as a last resort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great first post! Good call on limiting use of `refs` too.

One approach could be to keep some state in your ListItemPage component of which menu should be currently displayed.

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = { showMenu: null };
}
```

Then, in your `onMenuClick` function, receive the id of the item to show the menu for, and assign to state.

```
onMenuClick(id) {
  this.setState({ showMenu: id });
}
```

This would be passed into your Menu as follows.

```
showMenu={this.state.showMenu === listItem.id}
```

Closing the menu would just need to reset the value of `this.state.showMenu` to `null`.

This is assuming there would only be one menu displayed at a given time. If that's not true, let me know and I'll update.

Comment: Another option would be to have the `onClick` handler (and element you physically click) within the `Menu` component itself. That way you wouldn't need to pass a prop to the `Menu` component from the parent... but that would be a changing of the original setup I suppose. If you want to keep the current structure, this is the best way I can currently think of doing it :) .

Comment: That would work too, but if you only wanted one menu to display, I think the state would be an issue because peer items would need to hide their menus.

Comment: That is true, the solution I referenced would allow you view multiple menu's at once.

Comment: Which could be what OP was wanting.. either way its a fair alternative.

Comment: Cheers @BradBumbalough your first answer fits my use case best.